# How to add a pushbuttons on the top and bottom of the colorbar

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt4

Here is my sample peace of code.I am using gridlayout in my program to add my plot,slider and buttons.Here i needto arrange the up,down push buttons in top and bottom of the colorbar, but i didn't get exactly. when i am using self.glayout.addWidget(self.down,9,3,1,1)it was tacking the entire layout.can anyone please guide me.

```
self.up = QtGui.QPushButton(_("up"))
self.up.setMaximumWidth(40)
self.up.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
self.down = QtGui.QPushButton(_("down"))
self.down.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
self.down.setMaximumWidth(60)
self.newwidget = QtGui.QWidget()
self.glayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.newwidget)
self.canvas = MplCanvas()
self.nextBtn = QtGui.QPushButton(_("Next"))
self.previousBtn = QtGui.QPushButton(_("Previous"))
self.squareNum = QtGui.QLineEdit()
self.glayout.addWidget(self.canvas,0,0,10,10)
self.glayout.addWidget(self.up,1,4,1,1)
self.glayout.addWidget(self.down,9,4,1,1)
self.glayout.addWidget(self.sl,0,10,10,1)
self.glayout.addWidget(self.nextBtn,10,8,1,1)
self.glayout.addWidget(self.previousBtn,10,0,1,1)
self.glayout.addWidget(self.squareNum,10,4,1,1)
self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.newwidget)
```

my image:

[image]

excepted image:

[image]

Comment: please share a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

If your plot and color bar can be separated, I would recommend using a vertical layout (QVBoxLayout) for the color bar + up/down button portion of your plot.  You would add the widgets to the vertical layout like so:

```
vlayout = QVBoxLayout()
vlayout.addWidget(up_button)
vlayout.addWidget(color_bar) # I don't know which widget is your color bar
vlayout.addWidget(down_button)
```

Then, add this layout to your grid layout next to the main plot:

```
glayout = QGridLayout()
glayout.addWidget(plot, 0, 0)
glayout.addLayout(vlayout, 0, 1)
```

If instead, the issue is that your plot and color bar are combined as one and cannot be separated, you might want to instead sandwich your plot between two horizontal layouts like so:

```
vlayout = QVBoxLayout() # This is the main layout that will hold everything
top = QHBoxLayout()
bottom = QHBoxLayout()
top.addStretch(10) # This will push the button to the far right
top.addWidget(up_button, 1)
bottom.addStretch(10) # This will push the button to the far right
bottom.addWidget(down_button, 1)
vlayout.addLayout(top)
vlayout.addWidget(plot)
vlayout.addLayout(bottom)
```

I find in general that grid layouts are difficult to work with and that usually, vertical and horizontal layouts can be combined together to produce a better result that allows the layout manager to perform its primary function.